# Optional Parameters in Clickhouse Query

Tags: clickhouse

I am looking to frame a SQL in Clickhouse like below

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student
WHERE (:fname  IS NULL    OR FirstName = :fname)
  AND (:laname IS NULL    OR LastName  = :lname)
```

but experiencing an exception `DB::Exception: Cannot compare std::string with DB::Null`

Comment: Are FirstName and LastName defined as nullable columns?

Comment: no, Is it required to do??

Comment: Well, if you don't define the column as nullable it cannot store a null value. I'm not sure this is what's causing the problem here, though.

Comment: In any case, I recommend looking at the ClickHouse log file to see the exact query that was sent, since it's hard to know what :fname and :lname get converted into.

Comment: (:fname IS NULL   OR FirstName = :fname)  in this case will it check db column or the value passed to the named parameter?